# Unable to re-download a video with youtube-dl

Tags: command-line, youtube-dl

I have used this utility many times with great success. Unfortunately I incorrectly deleted a video that I had downloaded and `youtube-dl` won't let me do it again. I've tried removing `youtube-dl` and reinstalling it but it still won't work for me. Is there an option to get around this situation? I've searched the help file and can find nothing.

Here's what happens:-

```
allenb@arb-P7812 ~ $ youtube-dl --rm-cache-dir https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1glriB54oE
Removing cache dir /home/allenb/.cache/youtube-dl ...
[youtube] J1glriB54oE: Downloading webpage
[youtube] J1glriB54oE: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] J1glriB54oE: Downloading js player vflusCuE1
WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.
[download] Nat King Cole  An Evening With Nat King Cole HD-J1glriB54oE.mkv has already been downloaded and merged
allenb@arb-P7812 ~ $
```

I have successfully downloaded this video once, then accidentally deleted it, and now I want to download it again.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you give the error message?

Comment: Unless you link the video, the version of the app you're' using, what OS+version you're on, then you're not even making the minimum effort. It's pretty much OT for here AFAICT from your question content.

Comment: @Allen Try adding in `--no-continue` to your command line.

Comment: Usually for me, when new errors appears, i perform an upgrade of the package with `pip3 install youtube-dl --upgrade --user`, and they errors tend to resolve/dissapear in the next attempt. It may work for you too.